# iOS camera capture view already?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want a camera view that will capture a image to a local file or let user select an image fro m the local photo gallery. I think maybe someone has written good library/code for that. Maybe I can leverage it. Is there any good one already? Thanks. I am just avoiding to reinvent the wheel :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIImagePickerController is built into iOS and very easy to use, it allows for all the functionally you want.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

For the user to take a new photo:

"`UIImagePicker *imagePicker`"

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == YES)
{
    imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    imagePicker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}
```

Or to choose an existing photo from the device:

```
if( ![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] ) return;

imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

Be sure to include this!

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```